# Can I use strings within an array to name struct variables using concatenation, macros, or similar?

Tags: arrays, c, namespaces, c-strings, identifier

I have an array of animal names in the order that I intend to create each struct 'animal' and store it in farm_animals, a struct of animals.

`typedef struct ani animal;`

`animal* farm_animals[128] = {0};`

Although the below code is totally invalid, I have included it here to show exactly what I have thought of achieving in practice. I want to declare a variable of type animal corresponding to a string literal in the array, and then somehow use that literal as the name of the animal and store it in an array.

```
char* animal_names [] = {"Oliver", "Marcus", "Mike", "John", "Tom", "Daisy", "Lilac", "Rose", "Jim"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { 
        animal animal_names[i];
        farm_animals[i] = animal_names[i];
    }
```

I have researched and found many other similar posts which conclude that since C is a compiled not interpreted language, it is not possible to name a variable with the value of a string. However, I was wondering if it is possible to concatenate the string name with a suffix (like the index number) to create an entirely new 'string name' to refer to the animal. I have also though of a macro using an array or the same `animal_names` array, but this has not been clear for me to implement as a beginner.

I think this sort of idea in C is far-fetched, but I really wonder if there is a way to name these structs using a for loop and array of names, rather than manually creating 100+ structs.

Comment: You need some sort of map data structure - hash table, tree, etc. to give things names at runtime.

Comment: " it is not possible to name a variable with the value of a string"  That's because _it doesn't make sense_ to name a variable after a run-time value. Variable names exist _solely_ for the benefit of the programmer, they do not exist in the compiled binary nor do they have anything to do with the user/input of the program.

Comment: I don't imagine it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is not possible to dynamically name variables in C. If I understand correctly, you want to create an animal type corresponding to a string and then name it that name.

The advantage with using [structs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)) is that you can combine related/relevant data into a single variable (the struct) – which itself is a collection of multiple variables.

I would suggest organizing something like this:

```
typedef struct animal {
  char[20] name;
  char[20] type;
} animal;
```

You can replace the character array with a pointer to the string (`char*`) as well. Also, if you know the type of animals that could be created you can instead create an [enum](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum) like this:

```
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 20
#define MAX_NUM_ANIMALS 10

enum animalType {
  LION,
  ELEPHANT,
  FALCON,
  PARROT
};

typedef struct animal {
  char[MAX_NAME_LEN] name;
  enum animalType type;
} animal;

int main(void) {
  animal listOfAnimals[MAX_NUM_ANIMALS];

  listOfAnimals[0].type = PARROT;
  listOfAnimals[0].name = "my parrot";

  return 0;
}
```

So, instead of making 100+ structs, you would make an array of structs and store the type of animal as a data member. Then you could use some mapping mechanism or conditional logic to assign these types to the struct variables as per your needs.

Comment: I am new to programming so would really appreciate if you could clarify what kinds of mapping mechanisms are employed in such situations? IMO it would be based on the value of the other struct field (like specific names give rise to specific types and vice-versa) or the index numbers corresponding to elements of another array.

Comment: Do you just want to name the names you already have in an array of strings? That would be very simple – just loop through the string array and one by one assign the string to the struct data member: `listOfAnimals[i] = animalNamesStr[i]`.